# How to login with Python Requests when there is no name for the "button" input field

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to use requests to log into a site. Within my `post` request, I have to send all input fields for a form. It seems that the `name` field for the button input is non-existent, so I don't know which value to place in this field/ The input fields look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="email_address" size="40" class="input-text">
<input type="password" name="password" size="40" class="input-text">
<input type="submit" class="button-normal" value="Log In">
```

The for for the login page is:

```
<form name="login" action="https://www.southernhobby.com/login.php?action=process" method="post"></form>
```

I used the following code to attempt login:

```
payload = {'email_address': 'email', 'password': 'password', '':'Log In'}
login_url = 'https://www.southernhobby.com/login.php?action=process'
url = 'https://www.southernhobby.com/ccg-s/magic-the-gathering/c13_362/'

with requests.session() as s:
    s.get(login_url)
    s.post(login_url, data=payload)
    response = s.get(url)
    print(response.text)
```

The response url that I print is a page that will contain information that only logged in users can see. Of course code fails, and I believe it's because I'm not submitting the input value for the button. What can I put here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why your script isn't able to log you in the website is due to the absence of the header. It is always a good idea to implement it. overall you code should look like this

```
import requests

payload = {'email_address': 'email', 'password': 'password'}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Referer": "https://www.southernhobby.com/login.php",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Content-Length": "34",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
}

with requests.session() as s:
    s.post('https://www.southernhobby.com/login.php?action=process', data=payload, headers = headers)
    response = s.get('https://www.southernhobby.com/ccg-s/magic-the-gathering/c13_362/', headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
```

As you can see I've also removed `s.get(login_url)` and `'':'Log In'` as both of these snippets weren't contributing anything to your code.

Hope this helps you out :)